# Why doesn't simple google web search through getJSON always work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-search-api

This simple web search through google API is shaky. Sometimes it returns the 4 first findings (as it should), sometimes JSON thinks its a "success" but the responseData is null. Why am I getting these inconsistencies? Is it a asyncronic problem? How do I make it more stable? (When I search for images on google it is rock stable)

```
var baseUrl = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=0&q="; 
var searchTerm = "obama"; //Lots of hits

$(document).ready(function() // don't do anything until the document is loaded.
{  
$.getJSON(baseUrl + searchTerm +  "&callback=?", function(json) // call getJSON providing the complete url with search term and a JSONP callback
    {
    $.each(json.responseData.results, function(i, gResults){  
        console.log("title: " + gResults.titleNoFormatting);
    });
  });
});
```

---

When it fails I find this in the json data structure:

```
json.responseDetails: "Suspected Terms of Service Abuse. Please see
  http://code.google.com/apis/errors"
```

So Google think I'm attacking it with too many requests. Do I have to set an API key? right now I just include the

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="myAPIkey-Herevbng66r" />
```

But I'm running on my local computer so maybe it doesn't help…

Comment: I am having the same problem. It does have to do with the fact that you're running it locally. My same codebase running on the deployed server doesn't error out. This issue is putting a damper on my development, I'd be grateful if someone could weigh in with a reason or solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function(json) // call getJSON providing the complete url with search term and a JSONP callback
    {
       if (json.responseData === null)
          console.log("json returned nothing");
       else
         $.each(json.responseData.results, function(i, gResults){  
             console.log("title: " + gResults.titleNoFormatting);
         });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the purpose of this exercise is not to pick up any javascripts errors, but to make it more stable. "obama" should returns million of hits right? Then why does google/ajax/json return null and still believe it is a "success"?